# After doing a small change in the home page i get some error, even after reverting it back it doesnt fix

Tags: magento2

Please visit the website kiabzanew.site (will load a bit slow at the start). I get an error on the home page. Error filtering template: Invalid block type: item-image. Even after reverting the codes back it doesnt fix, please anyone know any fix?

Comment: Please run `php bin/magento cache:flush` command

Comment: Permanent solution is: you have called `item-image` block name somewhere either in your code on in any CMS Page/Static Block. create a block with this name or remove that name wherever you write it.

Comment: @temper your first solution of php bin/magento cache:flush, didnt work. Let me try the second one

Comment: I have removed item-image class from the home page code , now the error showing up is "Error filtering template: Invalid block type: 0"

Comment: This issue is not belong to some class, you have called a static block somewhere which is not created. Please identify the block on homepage and remove it,
Block  means static block which we create in admin panel and calls in cms pages

Comment: I tried but still no fix, i had the backup in server just restored it back.